# String manipulation: How isolate a word in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I am fairly new to `python`. I am wondering how would you extract `'FRI-AA-02'` from this string in a `dictionary`.

```
{ 
   "layers": {},
   "definitionExpression": "(UPPER(Auto_Trash_Route) = UPPER('FRI-AA-02'))"
}
```

More examples:

```
{
"id": "1",
"layers": {}"
"definitionExpression": "(UPPER(Auto_Yard_Route) = UPPER('FRI-AY-01'))"
}


{
"id": "4",
"layers": {}"
"definitionExpression": "(UPPER(Auto_Yard_Route) = UPPER('THU-AY-23'))"
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways, could you give us a couple more examples so we can get an idea of the pattern you`re going for

Comment: I'm pretty much looking for the most easiest way to split the string to get the 'FRI-AA-02'.

Comment: I thing using regular expression is the right way. You just need to explain to us what you are looking for. are you looking for a word standing in UPPER('...') or are you looking for a word made out of three letters a minus followed by two letters another minus and two numbers? Or dose the string look always the same except for the FRI-AA-02 part? In that case you can just cut off the rest. Tell me and I'll show you a way. If you are shure that the two quotes next to FRI-AA-02 are the only quotes ever appearing in the string you can take jpps solution.

Comment: The latter. The word FRI-AA-02 is the thing I am looking for. The string change when the user selects a different option and then gets put to a json file that i collect.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python string handling", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Well yea we know that but the thing you need to figure out is what "defines" this word. is it the format of the word or its place in the string. Or do you just want to know if the string contains FRI-AA-02?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use:

Using a sub string:

```
d= { 
   "layers": {},
   "definitionExpression": "(UPPER(Auto_Trash_Route) = UPPER('FRI-AA-02'))"
}

d['definitionExpression'][34:-3]
#returns 'FRI-AA-02'
```

using regular expressions:

```
import re
re.findall(r"(?<=')[^']+(?=')",d['definitionExpression'])
```

using split:

```
d['definitionExpression'].split("'")[1]
```

using regex with the format:

```
re.findall(r"\w{3}-\w{2}-\d{2}",d['definitionExpression'])
```

Comment: added one more example if that clarifies anything.

Comment: why would regex help? is it faster?

Comment: regex is a good way to find stuff in string if you can tell how it looks like FRI-AA-02 you know its three letters a minus two letters a minus and two numbers. you could use a reg ex to find a word whitch looks like that for example THU-BB-33

Comment: or regex could help you find things within some surroundings. like in your case FRI-AA-02 is surrounded by "UPPER('" and "')" you could use regex to find a string which is surrounded by that.

Comment: Alright thanks for the comprehensive answer. Would split be faster than using regex? I have a large data set that I work with and I would be concerned with performance time.

Comment: I think d['definitionExpression'][34:-3] would be a fast solution

Comment: Alright thanks. I will give you the check for the explanation and patience.

Comment: ok so I testet all ways. and all ways are faster then one millisecond so I think it doesn't really matter

Comment: Thanks for testing. Still learning python since I'm coming a land of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex to extract anything between the single quotes:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> d = { 
...    "layers": {},
...    "definitionExpression": "(UPPER(Auto_Trash_Route) = UPPER('FRI-AA-02'))"
... }
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", d['definitionExpression'])
['FRI-AA-02']
```

This can be useful if you have other cases where you must find multiple single quoted sub-strings:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = "'a', 'b'"
>>> re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", s)
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: "re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", s)" would actually include the quotes. try "(?<=')[^']+(?=')" instead.

Comment: I could not replicate this, can you provide an example where it would include the quotes?

Comment: re.findall(r"(?<=')[^']+(?=')",s)

Comment: well with your string it also returns ", " xD but I think this is no problem with the actual question

Comment: Thanks for the answer.